# Полоски в симуляции проекта Xcode

Tags: xcode

Столкнулся с первой проблемой Xcode ( пишу первое приложение, так что я еще зеленый ) - при запуске симуляции не соотносятся то что я делаю в interface Builder и то что показывает симуляция. Причем launchScreen отображается нормально, а вот main уже показывает исключительно полоски.

Ошибок Xcode никаких не выдает.

p.s Так как в этой среде и в этой сфере никогда не работал - не знаю какую информацию предоставить для упрощения вам жизни.
[image: Полоски в симуляции проекта]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Представьте код. Очевидно Вы пытаетесь вывести какие-то данные а таблице, покажите как вы это делаете

Comment: @schmidt9 Добрый вечер. Добавил еще один скриншот из Interface Builder, Вроде бы там нет никаких таблиц.

Comment: что вы вообще пытаетесь сделать

Comment: @schmidt9 форму авторизации, но для начала что бы корректно отображалась симуляция

Comment: не показывается экран с кнопкой?

Comment: @schmidt9, именно, показываются полоски. Искал в интернете на совершенно другую тему, и увидел в одном из вопросов схожую картину, но все равно не могу пока понять почему у него тоже полосы. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666575/sidebar-navigation-menu-on-storyboard

Comment: @schmidt9 добавил еще один скриншот, на нем текущая ситуация, думаю проблема в navigation controller, но это не точно)

Comment: Что у вас на этом экране показывает в дебаггере иерархии? https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html

Comment: @schmidt9, что-то страшное, не понимаю откуда он взял эту таблицу, она у меня нигде не указана... https://ibb.co/hMd6HM4

Comment: @schmidt9, пересоздал приложение, вроде все норм.

Comment: Вопрос теперь решен?

Comment: @schmidt9 Да) Спасибо за помощь!